# How to get the linked object file from target?

Tags: cmake

for example, I having

```
add_executable(myapp
    a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
)
```

is there any way to extract the obj files list from target `myapp`?

expected something like
`get_target_objects()`
return a list `a.obj b.obj c.obj`